# filter-branch --tree-filter with .gitignore

Tags: git

I am out of luck and don't know why git keeps adding the files to the index in my filter-branch workflow.

**filterBranch.sh**:

```sh
initDir="$1"
find . \( -name "*.gitignore" -or -name "*.gitkeep" -or -name "*.gitattributes" \) -exec rm -rf {} \; &>/dev/null # remove all git ignore stuff

cp -fR "$initDir"/* ./ && # Populate directory with initDir (new .gitignore)
    git rm --cached -qrf . && # Remove all files from index.
    git clean -fdqX || exit 1 # Clean all untracked files...

if [ "$(ls -1A "./storage" | wc -l)" != "1" ]; then
    echo "storage contains still more files....??"
    exit 1
fi
```

which I use in

```sh
git filter-branch --tree-filter "bash filterBranch.sh /tmp/iniDir" --prune-empty -- --all
```

I checked the added/overwritten `$initDir/storage/.gitignore`:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

which should remove all files in `./storage` except `.gitignore`.
However somehow git does not remove subfolder or files in `./storage` and the history gets not cleaned resulting in `exit 1` above...

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The tree filter *never uses your `.gitignore` at all*.  If you want your `.gitignore` obeyed, do not use the tree filter; if you want to use the tree filter, make sure *every* invocation leaves *exactly* the set of files you'd like behind, in the temporary tree that the filter is invoked upon.

(The filtering command you've written seems to be aimed more at an index filter, which would be much faster.  But note that an *index* filter does not have a work-tree to work with: it must do all of its work within Git's index.)

Note that the tree filter is incredibly slow, since it works by having Git literally check out every commit into a temporary directory (not your normal work-tree), then running the tree filter in that temporary directory.  Whatever files remain after the tree filter exits, those are the files that go in the new commit.  If there is a `.gitignore` file in that directory, that files' content goes into the new commit, but its content is itself ignored: all other files that are in that temporary directory *also* go into the new commit.  Then the temporary directory is destroyed, and a new temporary directory is created for the *next* commit to be copied.

(Remember, `git filter-branch` works by *copying* every original commit to a new-and-improved one, running your filters before making the new one.  The index filter is faster than the tree filter because this "copy" process consists only of copying to Git's index, letting you modify Git's index, and then committing whatever remains in Git's index afterward.  All of these operations take place with a temporary index and, if using tree-filter, temporary work-tree, in a temporary sub-directory.  Use the `-d` option to `filter-branch` to place this temporary sub-directory in a "fast" location to speed up filter-branch.  Better yet, switch to the new `git filter-repo` instead.)